# gridplot: set titles to columns, adjust scale of colorbar and space between images

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I have a code to generate subplots of images, the grid is 8 rows x 2 columns. Thee issue I'm having is that there is too much space between columns, I have adjusted the `wspace` of the `plt.GridSpec` but is not working. Also, I want to set names to the columns (at the bottom) like column a and column b, but when doing the same as I did with y-axis doesn't work. Last (sorry for all this questions), how can I change the vmax, vmin and midvalue of the colorbar just for the diff plots?? because as you can see the zero value is different for all of them (as their range values can vary).

This is the code I'm using and below is the image of how it is plotting. Thanks for your help.

```
images1 = [t, t2, f, f2, sf_cg, sf2_cg, diff_cg, diff2_cg, sf_p, sf2_p, diff_p, diff2_p,
          sf_pt, sf2_pt, diff_pt, diff2_pt]
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 20))
grid = plt.GridSpec(8, 2, wspace=0.01, hspace=0.01)
row_titles = ['T', 'F', 'SF CG', 'Diff CG', 'SF P', 
              'Diff P', 'SF PT', 'Diff PT']
col_titles = ['Column a', 'Column b']

for i in range(len(images1)):
    # define subplot using the grid
    ax = plt.subplot(grid[i])
    # turn off axis
    ax.axis('off')
    # rotate image
    rotated_image = np.rot90(images1[i].reshape(128, 128), k=1)
    # plot raw pixel data
    cmap = 'gray'
    if (i >= 6) and (i!=8) and (i!=9) and (i!=12) and (i!=13):  # Change the colormap for the diff subplots
        cmap = 'RdBu'
    im = ax.imshow(rotated_image, cmap=cmap)
    if i % 2 == 1:
        cbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=[plt.subplot(grid[i-1]), ax])
    if i % 2 == 0:
        row_idx = i // 2
        ax.annotate(row_titles[row_idx], xy=(0, 60), xytext=(-ax.yaxis.labelpad - 5, 0),
                    textcoords='offset points', va='center', ha='right', rotation='vertical',
                    fontsize=15)
    if i == 15 and i == 16:
        ax.annotate(col_titles, xy=(50, 120), xytext=(0, ax.xaxis.labelpad + 5),
                textcoords='offset points', va='center', ha='center', fontsize=15)


plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]